# Hibernate is not creating Tables in PostgreSQL in given Schema

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am using PostgreSQL and created table and schema called hib. When i create alien table in db and run the application it successfully persist the data into database. But if the table is not there in database then Hibernate is not creating table inside hib schema i think hibernate is not reading hdm2ddl.auto property which is mentioned in hibernate.cfg.xml. As per logs its not giving logs like creating or updating table if exists. It directly tries to insert values.
Tried many ways but its not working like create, update, create-drop.
Every time same error ERROR: relation "hib.alien" does not exist.
Here is persistent class.

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="hib.alien")
public class Alien {
    @Id
    private int aid;
    private String aname;
    private String acolor;

    public Alien() {}

    public Alien(int aid, String aname, String acolor) {
        this.aid = aid;
        this.aname = aname;;
        this.acolor = acolor;
    }

    public int getAid() {
        return aid;
    }

    public void setAid(int aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }

    public String getAname() {
        return aname;
    }

    public void setAname(String aname) {
        this.aname = aname;
    }

    public String getAcolor() {
        return acolor;
    }

    public void setAcolor(String acolor) {
        this.acolor = acolor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alien [aid=" + aid + ", aname=" + aname + ", acolor=" + acolor + "]";
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hib</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And Main Class

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Alien alien = new Alien(1, "Nagaraj Kharvi", "Red");
        System.out.println(alien);

        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Alien.class);
        SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(alien);
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

Here is logs :

```
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Mar 03, 2019 10:28:08 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: insert into hib.alien (acolor, aname, aid) values (?, ?, ?)
Mar 03, 2019 10:28:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
Mar 03, 2019 10:28:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: relation "hib.alien" does not exist
  Position: 13
Mar 03, 2019 10:28:09 AM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

Comment: `<property name="hdm2ddl.auto">CREATE</property>`. update-> will not create tables for you

Comment: Even create is also not working as i said.@Kid101

Comment: That could be because of the table name. change `@Table(name="hib.alien")` to `@Table(name="alien")` and set default schema in `hibernate.cfg.xml`
`<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="hib"/>` make sure schema is present in DB

Comment: <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="hib"/> compile time error it says Attribute value must be declared for element type property @Kid101

Comment: this has to be placed inside `session-factory` tag. Also, I'm starting to feel that you don't have a schema as `hib` but your DB name is `hib` and you are using a public schema-> if that is the case then just remove `hib.` from the table name and set `hdm2ddl.auto` -> create

Comment: I am clear about the information which i have given in the question. I have hib db and inside that i have two schema one is hib and another is public. I have used that hdm2ddl property inside session-factory tag only. Same error tried many times still not resolved. @Kid101

Comment: what version of hibernate?

Comment: hibernate :      <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
postgresql :     <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version> @Kid101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PostgreSQL entity should be like below, So that table will create
      in that schema.

```
 @Entity()
 @Table(name = "alien"  schema = "\"hib\"")
 public class Alien {
    @Id
    private int aid;
    public int getAid() {
        return aid;
    }
    public void setAid(int aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }
  }
```